# CreateProcess with a custom string

Tags: createprocess, file-not-found, tchar

I'm trying to run 'CreateProcess' in c, with a custom string that I build.
When I'm using a simple string like:

`TCHAR command[]= _T("MyApp.exe -OPTION1 -OPTION2")`

Everything seems to work fine.

But as I try to build a custom string (with getting MyApp OPTIONS from an other source), and concatenate the options to the string "MyApp.exe" using `sprintf_s` or `swprintf_s` the string I get is the same, but the process gives me an exit code of (2) - meaning (FILE_NOT_FOUND).

I'll be grateful for any help..

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find the answer,

If anyone had the same problem, you need to open your project's properties, and enter to:

Configuration Properties-> General

then set 'Chracter Set' to `Not Set`